# Making a form fixed

Tags: html, forms, header, fixed

I am trying to create a fixed header, with 'Welcome' and the following form (well it is actually only the beginning of a form). Welcome stays fixed, because the CSS style page tells all the headings to stay fixed. However my program won't let me put part of the form in a header. I can't figure out of to make this part of the form stay fixed too.

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>


 <form action="website.php" method="POST">
      <strong>Name:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="user"/>
         <strong>Gender<FONT COLOR="#FF0000">*</FONT></strong>
         <select name="Gender[]" double="double">
           <option value="Female">Female</option>
           <option value="Male">Male</option>
         </select></div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, there won't be any useful answers for you with the current code you have put up. Please include the header wrapping HTML and CSS. More helpful would be a http://jsfiddle.net/ replicating your problem.

Comment: You really mean people to select more than one gender? (no need to put `[]` in that name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="fixed">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>

<div class="form">
    <form action="website.php" method="POST">
       <strong>Name:</strong>
       <input type="text" name="user"/>
       <strong>Gender<FONT COLOR="#FF0000">*</FONT></strong>
       <select name="Gender[]" double="double">
           <option value="Female">Female</option>
           <option value="Male">Male</option>
       </select>
   </form>
</div>
```

**And the CSS**

```
.fixed
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.form
{
    margin: 80px auto;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

input, select
{
    width: 120px;
}
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jF2TF/2/)

Comment: This is great, but the Name and Gender input are still scrolling with the rest of the form. Only Welcome stays put.

Comment: One slight edit, it works perfectly now, thankyou very much!!

Answer (score 3):

write css code as

## CSS

```
#fixheader{
    position: fixed;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id='fixheader'>    
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>


 <form action="website.php" method="POST">
      <strong>Name:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="user"/>
         <strong>Gender<FONT COLOR="#FF0000">*</FONT></strong>
         <select name="Gender[]" double="double">
           <option value="Female">Female</option>
           <option value="Male">Male</option>
         </select></div>
```